# Vue.js - my multi accordion menu component is not working by toggle flags

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue. And I created `MultiAccordion` component for my test case. I want to open slide by `status[index]` flag. But this component is not working.  Why this is not working?

```
var MultiAccordion = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            items: [
                'cat',
                'dog',
                'bird',
            ],
            status: [],
        };
    },
    created: function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; ++i) {
            this.status.push(false);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleToggle: function(index) {
            this.status[index] = !this.status[index];
        },
    },
    template: `
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(val, index) in items">
            <button @click="handleToggle(index)">toggle</button>
            <div v-if="status[index]">
                {{ val }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    `,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue can not detect changes to an array when you assign value by index](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), i.e. the following is not reactive:

```
this.status[index] = !this.status[index];
```

You either have to use `Vue.set`:

```
this.$set(this.status, index, !this.status[index])
```

Or use `splice`:

```
this.status.splice(index, 1, !this.status[index])
```